# JSP/XML Help Dynamic html form

Tags: java, html, xml, jsp

I've **2** files:

1. **Order.jsp** which is used to connect to the database and retrieve data.
2. **display.xsl** is used to format the data.

Right now I'm hard coding my HTML form but I want to use the data from the database in my HTML form.

How would I do that?

**Order.jsp**

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <%@page contentType="text/xml" %>
      <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="display.xsl"?>
      <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>

       <Orders>

    <%


    // Connection
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");                  // load driver 
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Project");  // connect DB 

    // Execute query
    Statement   s       = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs= s.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM itemDetail" ); // Execute Query to return data from Statement into ResultSet

    while(rs.next()){
    %>
    <order>

    <%  out.print("<itemName> "+rs.getString("itemName")+"</itemName><quantity>      "+rs.getString("quantity")+ "</quantity><price> "+rs.getString("price")+"</price>");
    %>
    </order>
    <%  }

    rs.close();
    s.close();
    con.close();
    %>

    </Orders>
```

**display.xsl**

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:template match="/">

     <html>
     <head><title>Order Page</title></head>

    <body>
    <h2><b>List of Items available:</b></h2>
    <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Item Name</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Orders/order">
    <B>------------------------------------------</B>
    <br/>
    <tr>
    Item Name <B><xsl:value-of select="itemName"/></B>
    <br/>
    Quantity: <I><xsl:value-of select="quantity"/></I>
    <br/>
    Price: <I><xsl:value-of select="price"/></I>
    <br/>
    </tr>




        <form action="Confirm.jsp" method="POST">
            Please select item!
                <br/>
                <select name="itemName">
                <option value="GiftCard">GiftCard</option>
                <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
                <option value="Flower">Flower</option>
                </select>

                <br/>
                <br/>
                Qty!
                <select name="quantity">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                Price
                <input type="text" name="price"/>

                <input type="Hidden" name="SessionID" value="1234"/>

                <br/>

                <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
                </form>

    </body>
</html>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```